# Why the content of the string in initializer_list is empty?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am using a `map<string,initializer_list<string>>`, but I notice that the `initializer_list<string>` contains empty strings, i.e. `{"Red","Green","Blue"}` will be `{"","",""}`.

By replacing the `initializer_list` by a `vector`, the problem will be solved.

Why did I have this behavior?

```
std::map<std::string, std::initializer_list<std::string>> container = { {"Color",{"Red","Green","Blue"}},{"Car",{"BMW","Seat"}} };
for (const auto& item : container) {
    std::cout << item.first << std::endl;
    for (const auto& option : item.second)
    {
        std::cout << option << std::endl; //  option is always "", it should be "Red" or "Green" or "BMW" ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine on godbolt.org with gcc 10.1 x86-64.

Comment: By replacing the initializer_list  by a vector, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Please add that information to the question, instead of as a comment.

Comment: Visual Studio version= Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4, _MSC_VER= 1924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::initializer_list`s should normally be used only as function parameters, or in ranged-for loops. Use a proper container instead, like `std::vector`.

Your `initializer_list`s are dangling.

`initializer_list`s work like references pointing to temporary arrays, with the same [lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) rules:

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type `const T[N]`, in which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list. **The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an `initializer_list` object from the array extends the lifetime** of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.
>
> — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), emphasis mine

If you created `initializer_list` as a separate variable, the lifetime extension would work:

```
std::initializer_list<int> foo = {1, 2, 3};
```

But in your case it doesn't work, because:

> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.
>
> — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)

The process of constructing `std::map<std::string, std::initializer_list<std::string>>` involves copying/moving the `initializer_list` around, so there's no way it could work.